# Access wordpress network admin from different domain

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I'm running a Wordpress multisite instance configured with subdomains.
Developing locally no problem so far.
Once deployed I found out an auto redirect from `domain.com` to `www.domain.com` imposed by the system admins managing the servers.
But with this redirect it seems I cannot access the network admin panel anymore.

1. I log in `www.domain.com` or `www.domain.fr` or any configured mapped domain as admin
2. Once inside I get the dashboard for the site I logged in
3. I go on "network administration" and wordpress redirect me to the network domain aka `domain.com`
4. The autoredirect push me back again to `www.domain.com` and I get previous domain dashboard once more

Is there any way to access the network dashboard within the subdomains?

Comment: i think you should configure it on server so related .htaccess and wp-config.php file created on server.

Comment: What do you mean? The redirect is server handled: I have no redirect on the wp htaccess.

Comment: i mean follow create network procedure on server link : http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network and then after copy your themes and plugin to that server.

Comment: What's in your wp_site and wp_blogs tables?